# How to create a Tuple from an Array String

Tags: swift, string, tuples

I have String Array `["14 159", "14 163", "12 154", "14 160", "13 158", "14 161"]`
and I wonder how to create tuple from it? It should be `[(14, 159), (14, 163) .. etc]`

Comment: Start by using `split` and then `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map over the strings and split each one:

```swift
let input = ["14 159", "14 163", "12 154", "14 160", "13 158", "14 161"]

let result = input.map { str in
    let parts = str.split(separator: " ")
 
    guard parts.count == 2,
        let i1 = Int(parts[0]),
        let i2 = Int(parts[1]) {
        fatalError("Expected each string to have exactly two space separated numbers!")
    }
   
    return (i1, i2)
}

print(result)
```

Comment: This is a concise solution but you forgot to convert to Int at the end.

Answer (score -2):

List1 is your input.
List2 you declare wil be a list of tuples using: [(Int, Int)]

Then for the items in your list you will seperate them by a space and take the first half for the first item in the tuple and the second part for the second itme in the tuple.

Then you add tis tuple to list2.

```
import Foundation
var list1 = ["14 159", "14 163", "12 154", "14 160", "13 158", "14 161"]
var list2 : [(Int, Int)] = []
for items in list1{
    var turple = ((items.components(separatedBy: " ")[0] as NSString).integerValue, (items.components(separatedBy: " ")[1] as NSString).integerValue)
    list2.append(turple)
}

print(list2)
```

Comment: You assign `(0, 0)` to `turple` (did you mean `tuple`?), but you then immediate overwrite them. Why not just initialize it with the correct value form the start? `let tuple = (step1[0] as NSString).integerValue, step1[1] as NSString).integerValue)`

Comment: Yeah sorry i meant tuple and thats true you can definitely optemize this code. Il change it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).